# Width on P container or line breaks

Tags: html, css, frontend

Should paragraphs breaking point be set with the width of the container, or using br's?

Example:

```
<div  style="width: 30px;">
    <p>
        Foo bar test
    </p>
</div>
```

Or

```
<p>
    Foo<br>
    bar<br>
    test
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/APcU3/

I've always assumed that it should be by setting a width on the container. But I'm not frontend and quite a lot of the HTML templates I've been given to complete have used the BR method.

Comment: The front-end mantra is don't use structural code (br tags, for example) to determine it's style/layout. Rely on the width value in CSS, not <br>'s :)

Comment: That sounds like an answer, if you post it as one I'll be sure to mark as resolved and accepted if people agree. Thanks

Comment: Ben D has articulated the same point better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on specifically what you're trying to accomplish. If you're trying to get words to wrap to fit a specific width on the page then the first example is how you should approach it (**as a general rule you should try to adjust layout issues using `css`, not markup**).

However, if there is a logical reason why the lines need to break at those specific places, then the `<br />` method is appropriate (for instance, if you want to make sure that each word is on its own line regardless of the word-length, then using markup (`<br>`) is fine. However, even in these circumstances you may want to rely on more meaningful semantic markup unless there is a real logic to specifically using a break character. I.e:

```
<p class='thin_column'>
  <span>Foo</span> 
  <span>Bar</span>
  <span>test</span>
</p>
```

and include css rules:

```
.column {width:50px;}
.column span {display:block;}
```

This way you can still use CSS to radically adjust the layout but you'll force line-breaks after each word.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't ever mix style and structure** (or in this example content)! The `width`-method (used in an css-class and not inline) is the one and only way to achieve this.

the `<br>` element is only used to force a line break on a specific position. but that is content-dependend not a styling issue.